# allEffects() on GLMM gives an error message

Tags: r, effects

I get the following error messgae in R when I try to use allEffects() from the effects-package on a GLMM (mpc7j) created with glmer() from lme4:

```
> mpc7j<- glmer(correct_response ~ pc * Stim.cond + sess:pc + sess:Stim.cond +
                (1|item.no) + (1|id), data=d7nowl, family=binomial)

> allEffects(mpc7j)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Object 'sess' not found
```

When I use allEffects() on a different model ("dummy") on the same data without a term including "sess" in the fixed effects, it works just fine.

```
> dummy<- glmer(correct_response ~ pc * Stim.cond + (1|item.no) + (1|id),
                data=d7nowl, family=binomial)
```

I used str(mpc7j) to check my model and it looks like "sess" is in there as factor in the group of contrast treatments.

```
.. .. ..$ pc       : chr "contr.treatment"
.. .. ..$ Stim.cond: chr "contr.treatment"
.. .. ..$ sess     : chr "contr.treatment"
```

"sess" is a factor with 2 levels and refers to the time of testing (repeated measures, session1 and session2). One of the subjects I tested was tested only once, not twice like all the other subjects. Could that have anything to do with the error?

I would appreciate any pointers as to what I am doing wrong here or where I should look for a solution. I already googled the error message without success. The R documentation on the allEffects() function did not help me either. Help, please?

EDIT: When I try to use plotLMER.fnc() from languageR, I get this error:

```
> plotmpc7j<-plotLMER.fnc(mpc7j)
log odds are back-transformed to probabilities
Fehler: Indizierung außerhalb der Grenzen
```

The last line translates to something like "error: Indices outside bounds".

Comment: I am not really shocked that this doesn't work but will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is incomplete, I'm posting it as an answer rather than as a comment because it's long and contains a lot of code ... (I can go back and delete it later ...

The bottom line, so far, is that this is not a `glmer`/GLMM-specific problem, but a problem with a model that includes interaction terms (in this case `sess:pc` and `sess:Stim.cond`) without the main effects (`sess`) (in general such models are odd and often, but not always, wrong ... which may be why they're not handled by the `effects` package). I would consider contacting the package maintainers (`maintainer("effects")`) ...

Create a dummy data set with the correct structure:

```
d7nowl <- expand.grid(pc=factor(LETTERS[1:2]),
                      Stim.cond=factor(letters[1:2]),
                      sess=factor(1:2),
                      item.no=factor(1:10),id=factor(1:10))
d7nowl$correct_response <- rbinom(nrow(d7nowl),size=1,prob=0.5)
```

Fit the GLMM:

```
g1 <- glmer(correct_response ~ pc * Stim.cond + sess:pc + sess:Stim.cond +
            (1|item.no) + (1|id), data=d7nowl, family=binomial)

## reproduce error
try(allEffects(g1)) 
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'sess' not found
```

Now try a similar model with a GLM.

```
g2 <- glm(correct_response ~ pc * Stim.cond + sess:pc + sess:Stim.cond,
            data=d7nowl, family=binomial)    
try(allEffects(g2)) ## same error
```

`allEffects` gives us an answer (I haven't checked to see if it makes sense) if we *either* add the main effect of `sess` *or* (as pointed out in the original question) take out the interactions with `sess`.

```
g3 <- update(g2,.~.+sess)
try(allEffects(g3)) ## OK

g4 <- update(g2,.~.-sess:pc-sess:Stim.cond)
try(allEffects(g4)) ## OK
```

If I try to simplify still further `allEffects` still breaks, but with a different error message:

```
g5 <- glm(correct_response ~ pc + sess:pc, data=d7nowl, family=binomial)
try(allEffects(g5))
## Error in mod.matrix[, components] : subscript out of bounds
```

Understanding exactly what's going wrong will require digging into the guts of `effects:::analyze.model` (an internal utility function) to see where the logic goes wrong.

Comment: thanks for this explanation! I played around with it and if I substitute the ":" terms with "*" it works. Which, I guess, still  includes an interaction term...This does not really pertain to my original question, but why are models with ":" terms odd? Do you know where I could read up on that?

Comment: substituting `*` for `:` is equivalent to including the main effects in the model (`a*b` is synonymous with `a+b+a:b`, i.e. main effects plus interactions). Models with `:` terms (interactions) aren't odd: models with interactions *that do not also contain the relevant main effects* are odd. The general issue is called the *principle of marginality*: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf is a commonly cited reference, although it's a little oblique.  There are a few more references at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality ...